# Updating with apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, apt-get, gnome3, gnome-session

I'm running [Ubuntu 11.04](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_11.04_.28Natty_Narwhal.29) (Natty Narwhal) with gnome-shell, and I have a conflict in apt-get that don't let me upgrade / install new packages (my system is in Spanish. Because of that some output is in this language).

When I run apt-get upgrade:

```
Tal vez quiera ejecutar «apt-get -f install» para corregirlo. Los siguientes paquetes tienen dependencias incumplidas:  gnome-session : Depende: gnome-session-common (=
3.0.1-0ubuntu1~build2) pero 3.0.2-0ubuntu3~natty1 está instalado E: Dependencias incumplidas. Pruebe de nuevo usando -f.
```

gnome-sessions depend on gnome-session-common (=
    3.0.1-0ubuntu1~build2) but 3.0.2-0ubuntu3~natty1 is installed

If I run apt-get -f install:

```
dpkg: error al procesar /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-session_3.0.2-0ubuntu3~natty1_all.deb (--unpack):
 intentando sobreescribir `/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-shell.desktop', que está también en el paquete gnome-shell 3.0.1-0ubuntu1~build1
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-session_3.0.2-0ubuntu3~natty1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have a similar error:

```
apt-get clean
apt-get autoclean
```

With or without "-f" I have similar output.

File `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty main restricted

deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates main restricted

deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty universe
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates universe

deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty multiverse
deb http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty-security multiverse

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main


deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu natty main
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What's in your /etc/apt/sources.list? There must be something other than the regular Ubuntu archives, since Ubuntu package search doesn't show mention gnome-sessions at all (just gnome-session), and [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1758187) references a Gnome PPA.

Answer (score 1):

I think the mirror you currently use is broken, or not totally synced.
Simply switch mirrors with Synaptic, or use a text editor.

With Synaptic, you can do the switch from the options.
If you want to use a text editor, do the following:
1) Open up a terminal
2) Type: `gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
3) Edit -> Replace All.
4) Replace all the country strings, to an anouther country.

Like in my case, I have "hu.archive." by default, which is the worse mirror I've ever seen. So I go there after every install, and change the "hu" part to "de" as in Germany. So it looks like this: `de.archive.` (All the lines where there is a country PREfix.)

After this, do an `apt-get update` and then, try the upgrade (again).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the stuff you added to source.list. Execute this command first:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

After you have entered your password and it is added, do this:

```
$ gksu apt-get update
```

Afterwords, upgrade all packages with

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You will then require gnome-shell:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

Afterwards, just reboot and at login you should be able to select Gnome Shell Desktop from the menu

Comment: This post helped me resolve a small apt-get update issue I was having earlier. Thanks!